# Word Headings Not Aligned

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, styles

I've been formatting a report in Word using Heading styles (first time I've done this) and I can't get them to properly align. As shown in my screenshot attached, it seems that some headings align the left hand side of the number/letter with the tab stop, while others use the dot at the right hand side to align. This results in a messy looking document. Where in settings can I change this?

[image]

Comment: Master how-to: https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by reformatting the numbering in the styles menu and making sure the alignment was all set to "left."

Answer (score 0):

**Copy-pasting formats (alignments) from a good heading/paragraph to bad**

1. Click 3 times on the paragraph with correct alignment. After clicking 3 times, the whole paragraph should be selected.
2. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy only the format of the paragraph.
3. Click 3 times on the paragraph with bad alignment.
4. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the format. Now alignments of both paragraphs should match.